# Store and transfer a Machine Learning model through K8S CRD?

Tags: python, kubernetes, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am doing a crazy thing, maybe.

The idea is I want to train a machine learning model with python scikit-learn, then I get the fitted model object and then I can store it as a pickle file on the disk, and then I want to send this to some daemonsets on some nodes.

And since this whole process is based on K8S cluster, seems like the only way to solve this is through APIServer so I need to create a CRD for this?

If I need to create a CRD, then the pickle file need to be encoded as a binary string or something, and put it into the CRD's some value.

I know this is not the best practice. So is there any other suggestions? Is my solution realizable?

Comment: ML models can be pretty big, but IIRC Kubernetes objects have a 1 MB size limit.  I don't think passing an entire model in a custom resource will work.

Comment: @DavidMaze a SVM scikit-learn model seems like can be pickled into bytes string, and it may has a size correlataed with your training data size. In my situation this is around 50KB, so it's okay to put into CRs?